# Checking roles with ASP:Net Identity 2.1 does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I upgraded my ASP.Net MVC Core application from 1.1 to 2.1 including migrating ASP.Net Identity from 1.1 to 2.1.

I got the things working including ASP.Net Identity EntityFramework integration using Sqlite.

My `startup.cs` configuration looks like [this](https://github.com/mduu/tauchbolde/blob/develop/src/Tauchbolde.Web/Startup.cs):

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(PolicyNames.RequireTauchbold, policy => policy.RequireRole(Rolenames.Tauchbold));
        });
```

And in Configure() I have:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
[Authorize(Policy = PolicyNames.RequireTauchbold)]
public class EventController : Controller
{
    ...
```

The entire source-code can be found here on GitHub.

## Problem

The problem is that the above check on the controller always return "access denied" even if I am properly logged in and have the role assigned. I don't know that can go wrong here. Do anybody have an idea what I could miss [here](https://github.com/mduu/tauchbolde)?

### Update

I figured, that the plain, empty `[Authorize]` attribute works (enforces the login) but the `[Authorize(Policy = '...')]` does not recognise the role. I've checked the db tables but they look good to me. Do I needs to configure anything else in the database beside `ÀspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles` ?

## Update 2:

I got it work with the solution from @itminus but had to add a call to `AddDefaultUI()` in the startup to get the Login and Register working again. So my startup now contains these lines to configure Identity:

```
        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested your code . Since `AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()` in the version of `2.1.x` won't enable `Role` by default , I change your code as below :

```
//services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
//    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

To test with the above code , I register a new user and add the role for the user :

```
await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Rolenames.Tauchbold));
var user= await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, Rolenames.Tauchbold);
```

And sign out firstly and sign in again , it works now :

[image]

Comment: Sounds promissing! What are your `_roleManger` and `_userManager` types? Did you inject them and if so how did you register them with the container?

Comment: Got creation code work with `RoleManager<>` and `UserManager<>` but now "Login" and "Register" don't do anything anymore. Did you change something here? Scaffold them?

Comment: Got this working too by adding a call to `AddDefaultUI()` in the startup. Thank you sooo much for these pointers!

Comment: @Marc I just scaffold them and didn't add a  `.AddDefaultUI()` manually . I do this because we might custom the user and role in future , and in that case , we have to custom the `userManager` and `roleManager` in the Razor pages . By the way , personally , I think it's good to let my DbContext inherits from `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser,IdentityRole>` explicitly , so I make it to be`public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole,string>`  .